# Realm List vs LinkingObjects performance

Tags: ios, swift, realm

If I have understood correctly, then LinkingObjects will be loaded only when i access the property?!

The Lists relationship is written in the realm database?!

So could the access to the relationships be faster if i use Lists?
Maybe it will use more storage.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkingObjects` and `List` provide different semantics, so it doesn't make much sense to choose between them based on performance.